# What is the difference between "Registry" and "Directory"

Tags: meaning

We are building a software system that maintains a collection of participating entities, and I'm trying to determine if it is more appropriately termed a registry or a directory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about technical language, not general English.

Comment: @DJClayworth - but doesn't technical language come from general english?  I'm coming from a software development background and I can tell you that most concepts or terminologies come from general english definitions.

Comment: @djclayworth The OP asks about the meaning in general English, not technical, so I would say the question is fine.

Answer (score 3):

From various dictionary definitions it is not easy to distinguish between the two. From current usage I would say it is as follows:

1. A *registry* is an official record keeping institution, such as the UK Land Registry. Ownership of all land in the UK is registered there. Unless you are in there, it might be hard/impossible to prove that you own a piece of land.
2. A *directory* is a collection, which does not need to be either official or comprehensive, such as the *telephone directory*. You can happily make and receive phone calls, whether you are in the directory or not.

If the participating entities enter the collection voluntarily, and can operate without doing so, I would suggest you use *directory*; a *registry* would require them to be part of it.

However, despite its name, use of the [Windows Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) is not mandatory for applications.